# WooCommerce - Getting a Free product for one bought promotion for selected products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I have a WooCommerce web site. I would like to add a promotion like **buy 1 and Get 1 Free** for some selected products.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: There are few plugins which do this. [Pricing Deals for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pricing-deals-for-woocommerce/), [WooCommerce Multiple Free Gift](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-multiple-free-gift/).

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible without a plugin. There is different ways but the best and easy one is that one… **Based on product category and on auto-applied coupon of 50%** *(easy and better).*

1) **First create a  product category** in backend Products > categories, for example 'two4one'. 
Set this **category** to all the products you want to have this promotional plan (2 for one)

2)**Creating a special coupon in woocommerce (to be auto-applied):**

> In woocommerce create a coupon **that you will name for example `'2for1'`**. 
> You will make this special settings to it:
>
> - General > Discount type: **Product % Discount**
> - General > Coupon Amount: **`50`**  *(this is a percent see line above)*
> - Usage Restriction > Individual use only: *enabled*
> - Usage Restriction > Product categories: **`two4one`** *(add your special product category here)*
>
> So this coupon **restrict the discount only** to **`two4one`** category products. If all products with  **`two4one`** category are removed from cart, the coupon will be removed too.

**3) The code:** Once the coupon is created and correctly set, you can use this hooked functions code:

```
// Add to Cart 2 products at the same time of the "two4one" product category
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'add_to_cart_qty_by_two', 10 );
function add_to_cart_qty_by_two($cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data) {

    // When a product has 'two4one' as category increment quantity by one (2 products)
    if( has_term( 'two4one', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
        $quantity += $quantity;
        WC()->cart->set_quantity($cart_item_key, $quantity);
    }
}

// Auto applying coupon if products with two4one" category are in cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'auto_add_a_coupon_discount', 10 );
function auto_add_a_coupon_discount( $cart_object ) {

    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $item ) {
        // When a product has 'two4one' as category auto apply coupon '2for1'.
        if( has_term( 'two4one', 'product_cat', $item["product_id"] ) && !$cart_object->has_discount('2for1') )
            WC()->cart->add_discount('2for1');
    }
}

// If customer discrease or increse quantity it will be restored to an even number on checkout
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'checking_promotional_products', 10 );
function checking_promotional_products() {

    foreach ( WC()->cart->cart_contents as $item_key => $item ) {
        // if it's a promo product category and quantity is an even number
        if( has_term( 'two4one', 'product_cat', $item["product_id"] ) && $item["quantity"] % 2 != 0 ) {
            // checking that item quantity is always an even number (if not adds 1)
            $quantity = $item["quantity"] + 1;
            WC()->cart->set_quantity($item_key, $quantity);
        }
    }
}
```

*This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or in any plugin file.*

Comment: LoicTheAztec: very good solution, I too was thinking as how to do this without any plugin, but this solution did't come to my mind. I have been following you from last 2 weeks, and have learn a lot by reading your answers. Thanks for all such good answers.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec is not working for me. please give other example